# Run process on the same monitor as the parent process

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I have an MFC application written in C++ that launches Notepad via `ShellExecuteEx()`. Assuming both applications are running on a dual monitor system, how do I make sure that Notepad is opened on the same monitor as the main application?

Comment: You can set the `SEE_MASK_HMONITOR` bit in the `fMask` member of the `SHELLEXECUTEINFO` structure and specify the monitor handle in the `hMonitor` member.

Comment: … and use the [`MonitorFromWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-monitorfromwindow) API to get the handle of the monitor that your app's main window is (mostly) in.

Comment: Thanks Adrian. I'll test this on Monday as I don't currently have access to a dual monitor system. Assuming Notepad has already been started, is it possible to move it to the same monitor as the other application?

Comment: @melanie93 given the target `HMONITOR` and `HWND` to move, you can use `GetMonitorInfo()` to get the screen rectangle of the monitor and then use `SetWindowPos()` to move the window within that rectangle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `SEE_MASK_HMONITOR` bit in the `fMask` member of the [`SHELLEXECTUTEINFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/ns-shellapi-shellexecuteinfoa) structure and specify the handle of the required monitor in the `hMonitor` member. You can get the monitor handle of your application's main window using the [`MonitorFromWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-monitorfromwindow) API call.

The following code (or something very like it) should do the trick:

```cpp
void RunNotepadOnMyMonitor() {
    SHELLEXECUTEINFO sei;
    memset(&sei, 0, sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO));
    sei.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
    sei.fMask = SEE_MASK_HMONITOR;
    sei.lpVerb = _T("open");        // Optional in this case: it's the default
    sei.lpFile = _T("notepad.exe");
    sei.lpParameters = nullptr;     // Add name of file to open - if you want!
    sei.nShow = SW_SHOW;
    sei.hMonitor = ::MonitorFromWindow(AfxGetMainWnd()->GetSafeHwnd(), MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST);
    ShellExecuteEx(&sei);
}
```

Comment: internal `ShellExecuteEx` call `CreateProcessW` for start process. so must be option encode this in [`STARTUPINFOW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-startupinfow) structure. and really - *If a process is launched from the taskbar or jump list, the system sets `hStdOutput` to a handle to the monitor that contains the taskbar or jump list used to launch the process.*. so we need place `hMonitor` in `hStdOutput`. what is undocumented here - need also use `0x400` flag in `dwFlags`.

Comment: but main in next - *The process **can** then use the handle to position its windows.* - so unsure are windows will be force position by system or process need do this by self

Comment: @RbMm No offence, but it's unclear to me what you're trying to say (but I know you know deep stuff about how `WinAPI` calls work)! But how about this: if the user moves the app's main window to a different monitor, then `hStdOutput` will still point to its *original* monitor - not the one that the app's window has since moved to. And what does the `0x400` in `dwFlags` (in the `MonitorFromWindow` call?) actually do?

Comment: i simply try explain how `SEE_MASK_HMONITOR` work internal. really `sei.hMonitor` moved to `STARTUPINFOW::hStdOutput` and undocumented flag `STARTF_xxx == 0x400` is set in `STARTUPINFOW::dwFlags`. what i can not test (because have only single monitor) - are system in this case force initial place window on given monitor or application must do this by self. *if the user moves the app's main window to a different monitor, then hStdOutput will still point to its original monitor* - of course - `hStdOutput` will not change and can affect only initial position

Comment: @RbMm OK - that's a lot clearer now. Also, I only have a single monitor system until tomorrow - so we're all waiting to see what *actually* happens! 

Comment: your code have the same effect as this - https://pastebin.com/VsFnYJcP . interesting that `hStdInput` can be used also as hotkey and special flag - `STARTF_USEHOTKEY` (0x200) is documented for this. that `hStdOutput` can be alternative use as `hMonitor` documented, but flag for this (0x400) - not documented. if you look for `STARTF_` constants in *winbase.h* - exist gap at 0x400 value. i be name it `STARTF_USEHMONITOR`